# I have photos on my phone that I can't delete

Tags: photos, storage, iphone

My photos are taking up 5 GB on my phone and I only have about 100 of them. I do have a bunch of ghost photos that I can't delete though. They are from my old phone which is not an apple product and I am having storage issues because of it.

Comment: How did you add your old photos to your iPhone? What kind of phone is it?

Comment: I meant what kind of phone _was_ it (your old phone).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an iPhone; probably best to backup your phone through iTunes then do a factory reset and restore your data. If they are ghost/misbehaving photos then they won't be included in the backup and hence won't be restored back onto your phone.

Comment: If the pictures are are synced via iTunes they will come back even after a factory reset, and those pictures can't be erased from the phone; they have to be erased from the preferences on iTunes. That's why I asked how the OP was syncing them.